Laravel get collection keys when second key matches value
Hello i like to get all key values if other key matches string.
here is an example function thats get only values from the model:
$where = [];
$where['state'] = PirepState::ACCEPTED;
$where['airline_id'] = $airline_id;
$where['source'] = PirepSource::ACARS;

$average_lrate = Pirep::where($where)->avg('landing_rate');
$stats[__('DBasic::widgets.alrate')] = number_format(abs($average_lrate)) . ' ft/min';

This I have tried to change to access a collection and get all key values if second key matches a string:
$where = [];
$where['state'] = PirepState::ACCEPTED;
$where['airline_id'] = $airline_id;
$where['source'] = PirepSource::ACARS;

$average_grate = Pirep::where($where)->avg('fields->where(slug, "landing-g-force")->value(value)->all()');
$stats[__('DBasic::widgets.agrate')] = number_format(abs($average_grate)) . ' g';

Thats the model of the fields attribute:
/**
* Get the pirep_fields and then the pirep_field_values and
* merge them together. If a field value doesn't exist then add in a fake one
*/
public function fields(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(get: function ($_, $attrs) {
        $custom_fields = PirepField::whereIn('pirep_source', [$this->source, PirepFieldSource::BOTH])->get();
        $field_values = PirepFieldValue::where('pirep_id', $this->id)->orderBy(
            'created_at',
            'asc'
        )->get();

        // Merge the field values into $fields
        foreach ($custom_fields as $field) {
            $has_value = $field_values->firstWhere('slug', $field->slug);
            if (!$has_value) {
                $field_values->push(
                    new PirepFieldValue([
                        'pirep_id' => $this->id,
                        'name'     => $field->name,
                        'slug'     => $field->slug,
                        'value'    => '',
                        'source'   => PirepFieldSource::MANUAL,
                    ])
                );
            }
        }

        return $field_values;
    });
}

Thats the model of 'field':
/**
* Return a custom field value
*
* @param $field_name
*
* @return string
*/
public function field($field_name): string
{
    $field = $this->fields->where('name', $field_name)->first();
    if ($field) {
        return $field['value'];
    }

    return '';
}

This and many more I tried:
$average_grate = Pirep::where($where)->avg('fields->where(slug, "landing-g-force")->value(value)->all()');

resulted in: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fields' in 'field list'
$average_grate = Pirep::where($where)->avg('fields.value->where(slug, "landing-g-force")->get()');

resulted in: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fields.value' in 'field list'

you can't run a DB query on an attribute calculated in memory, you need to access the relation to filter based on these custom fields

You could get the results, then use collection methods to aggregate them into an average. $query->get()->avg(field). You should have access to your Attribute at that point. However I think it's going to be very slow.
